# How to use axios in visual studio code extensions with webview

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using this sample to develop my plugin. And I want to fetch some remote data and display data in webview. My question is how to use axios or other libs in this environment. Thanks.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-sample

Answer (score 0):

if you want get data from api, you can use request.
`npm install request --save` you can you `axios` instead of `request`

```
import request = require('request');

const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
request({
  headers: {}, // add here headers if you needed
  uri: URL,
  method: 'GET', 
  // bodyData will come here if method is POST
  }, (err, res, body) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(data);
  // here call other stuff wants to do.
});
```

Comment: This example does not work for me and I get an error `Activating extension failed`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used webview, but for a simple extension `axios` is used like this, in `extension.js`:

```js
const vscode = require('vscode');
const axios = require('axios');

async function activate(context) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://example.com/",
      { headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" } }
    );
    console.log(res.data);
  } catch(e){ console.log(e) }
  // ...
}

function deactivate() {}
module.exports = { activate, deactivate }
```

I hope a similar thing will work in webview.